# Reduce clang-generated code size for ARM

Tags: c, gcc, arm, clang

I compare code generated by clang and generated by gcc for arm.

Unfortunately, gcc's code more often has less instructions. 
I am just curious - is it possible to reduce code, generated by clang? 
Maybe I should use some options to do so...

Please, consider very simple example:

```
> cat test.c
int to_upper(int c)  
{  
   if(c < 'a' || c > 'z') return c; 
   else return c - ('a' - 'A');  
}

> clang -target arm-none-eabi -Oz -c -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 -msoft-float ./test.c -o ./clang_test.o 
> /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -Os -c -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 -msoft-float ./test.c -o ./gcc_test.o 

> /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -d ./clang_test.o 
./clang_test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm 
Disassembly of section .text: 
00000000 <to_upper>: 
   0:   4602        mov r2, r0 
   2:   3a61        subs    r2, #97 ; 0x61 
   4:   4601        mov r1, r0 
   6:   3920        subs    r1, #32 
   8:   2a19        cmp r2, #25 
   a:   d800        bhi.n   e <to_upper+0xe>
   c:   4608        mov r0, r1 
   e:   4770        bx  lr 

> /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -d ./gcc_test.o 
./gcc_test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm 
Disassembly of section .text: 
00000000 <to_upper>: 
   0:   1c03        adds    r3, r0, #0 
   2:   3b61        subs    r3, #97 ; 0x61 
   4:   2b19        cmp r3, #25 
   6:   d800        bhi.n   a <to_upper+0xa>
   8:   3820        subs    r0, #32 
   a:   4770        bx  lr
```

Why so much difference in such simple code? 
Can clang generate less code in this case? At least as gcc?

Note: if we change cpu to -mcpu=cortex-a5 (other options remains the same), then clang ang gcc produce 
absolutely identical code:

```
00000000 <to_upper>: 
   0:   f1a0 0361 sub.w r3, r0, #97 ; 0x61 
   4:   2b19        cmp r3, #25 
   6:   bf98        it  ls 
   8:   3820        subls   r0, #32 
   a:   4770        bx  lr
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3

clang version 3.7.1 (tags/RELEASE_371/final) 
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
Thread model: posix

arm-none-eabi-gcc (4.8.2-14ubuntu1+6) 4.8.2

Comment: That's funny. You should report a bug.

Comment: Cortex-A5 is not thumb2 by default. And it is a very different architecture than M0. M0 does not even support all T2 instructions.

Comment: Any reason why you don't write the function as `int to_upper (int c) {
  if(c < 'a' || c > 'z')
    return c;
  else
    return c - ('a' - 'A');
}`?

Comment: No reason. Generated code unfortunately not changes. This is a legacy code base by the way.

Comment: That was my point, the code I posted will yield identical machine code. It is just far more readable.

Comment: Update post with this version. Thank you. So it seems to be a bug?

Comment: Seems likle Clang is optimizing the "hit" case where input is between `'a'` and `'z'`: `c-32` is computed early and predicatedly so that when the function need the result to return, it's guaranteed to be ready. However the gcc version computes `c-32` "lazily" so the function to wait for the pipeline to drain before it can have the result and return. The gcc version seems to have less instructions but after `subs` there are a few invisible cycles before the function ends. Two techniques may result in very close performance, but I like the Clang one because it accurately predicted the use case.

Comment: With `a5` flag, both gcc and clang uses conditional execution and removed the branch.

Comment: Yeah. But there is a way to force clang produce less code in this case? If I want lesser code (as gcc), not more performance?

Comment: with clang you can optimize at compile time or optimize later, also combine objects or combine the entire project and then optimize it, something I dont think you can do with gnu tools as this is all done at the intermediate code level not after you have already hit the target machine code.   early experiments and common sense dictates to not optimize until later so the optimizer has more information to work with.

Comment: for this simple example.  there is no reason to assume that any compiler in particular is going to come up with every possible optimization a human can find.  it is almost always possible on a real world sized project to further optimize what comes out of the compiler.   clang/llvm have been struggling to get to where gcc/gnu was. at the same time over the last two major versions gcc's optimizers have gotten worse.

Comment: did you try compiling to bytecode, then optimizing at the bytecode level then llc out to the target?  you try any other optimization flags?  also remember less code doesnt mean better optimized. I would have to study your exact example more carefully but less is not always more.

Comment: you should also mix in gcc 3.x and 5.x, and maybe the prior version of llvm as well...may open your eyes some more.

Comment: there is no reason to ever assume that two compilers or two versions of the same compiler are going to produce the same output.  that is not what compilers do.  that is why there is more than one compiler out there, because they are different front to back not just the output but in every way

Comment: `clang` uses the same values for the `-O` (optimize) option as `gcc`.  However, the posted code uses different values.  Suggest setting both `-O` optimization values the same, otherwise the code with always be different.

Comment: Then I have to say you are doing a code size version of premature optimization.

Comment: I tried with -Os and -O3. Generated coge not reduced

Comment: I have not tried to optimize for size in a long time but I have seen compilers that the optimize for speed produced smaller binaries than the optimize for size.  Try to understand the task of the compiler, for any general purpose language, the work involved just producing accurate/working code, then trying to optimize that at all is a big deal.   You may wish every few line program you write would result in the asm you expect, but the tool cannot be tuned for every wish everyone has, it does what it can within the limits of the authors of that tool or the limits of the task at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, clang cannot generate less code in this case. And also in many others.

Historically, very few code size optimizations have been implemented in LLVM. When optimizing for code size, GCC typically outperforms LLVM significantly.

[Here presentation](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2016-03/#presentation14), where done a closer look at the comparing GCC and Clang in terms of code size optimization.

[Presentation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFgwEEBw7U0&feature=youtu.be)